# Non-abelian ray class fields for local fields

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory, langlands-conjectures, class-field-theory

Let $K$ be a non-Archimedean local field. Then, thanks to work of [Koch](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/mana.19670350509) (when $K$ has positive characteristic) and [Jannsen-Wingberg](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01393199) (when $K$ has characteristic zero, and odd residual characteristic) we know a completely explicit presentation of the absolute Galois group $\Gamma_K := \mathrm{Gal}(K^\text{sep}/K)$, where $K^\text{sep}$ denotes the separable closure of $K$. For example, when $K$ has characteristic zero and odd residual characteristic $p$, the Galois group $\Gamma_K$ can be generated by $N+3$ elements $\sigma, \tau, x_0,\dots,x_N$, where $N = [K \colon \mathbb{Q}_p]$ and $\sigma$ is a lift of Frobenius, while $\tau$ is a lift of the generator of the tamely ramified Galois group $\mathrm{Gal}(K^{\text{tame}}/K^\text{unr})$, and $x_0,\dots,x_N$ generate the wildly ramified part $\mathrm{Gal}(K^\text{sep}/K^\text{tame})$.
Here, $K^\text{unr}$ denotes the maximal unramified extension of $K$, and $K^\text{tame}$ denotes the maximal tamely ramified extension of $K$.
When $K$ has positive characteristic, the result is similar but one has to replace $x_0,\dots,x_N$ by countably many generators. In both cases, the relations between these elements are all completely determined.

The question I have is whether there is a natural way to filter $\Gamma_K$ by subgroups of finite index, using this presentation, similarly to what happens with $\Gamma_K^\text{ab}$. More precisely, this group can be filtered by transfering the filtration $\{ 1 + \mathfrak{m}_K^n \}_{n=0}^{+\infty}$ from the group of units $\mathcal{O}_K^\times$ of the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$ (whose maximal ideal is denoted by $\mathfrak{m}_K$) to the Galois group $\Gamma_K^\text{ab} = \mathrm{Gal}(K^\text{ab}/K)$ via the local Artin map $[K,\cdot] \colon K^\times \to \Gamma_K^\text{ab}$. This gives rise to local analogues of the usual ray class fields, which can be explicitly described thanks to Lubin-Tate theory. Is there any analogous result which is known or at least conjectured in the non-abelian case? To sum up, is there a preferred family of finite extensions of $K$ which filters the whole separable closure $K^\text{sep}$, and can maybe be explicitly described by means of non-abelian analogues of Lubin-Tate theory?

Perhaps a related, very vague question would be to describe explicitly the compatibility between the local Langlands correspondence (say for $\mathrm{GL}_n$ over $K$) and this explicit presentation of $\Gamma_K$. I unfortunately don't know whether this is known to the experts, or it already appears in the literature, and I apologize if this is the case.

Comment: I don't have a good answer, but since $n$ in the filtration denotes the conductor, this is basically asking for a non-abelian notion of conductor. The conductor detects higher ramification groups in the upper numbering in the abelian case, so I guess the natural generalization is just higher ramification groups in the upper numbering. Of course, they do not jump at integers anymore, but that's still a filtration. An unsatisfying one however...